# For using a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, text-mining, textblob

I have a df structured as follows:

| text | sentiment |
| --- | --- |
| XXXXX | yes |
| YYYYYY | no |

I'm trying to check the accuracy manually, according to this code ... however, I can't apply it to my DF. and I have the following error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

```
    for text, sentiment in df:
    classification = TextBlob(text).sentiment.polarity

if (classification <=0 and sentiment == "no"):
    Sum_classification +=1
elif (classification >=0 and sentiment =="yes"):
    Sum_classification +=1  

print("the Accuracy is ", Sum_classification/len(df))
```

So, I decided to transform this to the list using the following code, which makes the code run without error, but I don't have the expected result, once I get

> the Accuracy is 0.0

```
list = list(zip(df_test['text'], df_test['sentiment']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the following to iterate through each row in your DataFrame:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
```

You can then access the sentiment text with

```
row.sentiment
```

So you would probably want to do something like this:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    sentiment = row.sentiment
    classification = TextBlob(sentiment).polarity
```

Answer (score 0):

lazy work:

```
# create a int column
df['int sentiment'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == 'yes' else 0)

avg = sum(df['int sentiment'])/len(df['int sentiment'])

print(f'Average is {avg}')
```

Now you won't need to run the code and load all data frame again for each interaction, you will work with only one column to build your metrics.